# laravel genera un form y lo envía automáticamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, api

Estoy intentando integrar la API de Redsys en mi plataforma, ya está integrada, pero desde arriba me han pedido que se haga con un modal todo el proceso del pago, así que estoy intentándolo y cuando finaliza el proceso de creación de la petición a redsys, esta retorna un form con un script que envía dicho formulario.

He intentado ponerlo en el src del iframe que he creado, pero como es logico no me ejecuta ese script y por lo tanto no me abre la página del formulario del pago

en el controller retorno esto:

```
<form action="https://sis.redsys.es/sis/realizarPago" method="post" id="redsys_form" name="redsys_form" >
            <input type="hidden" name="Ds_MerchantParameters" value="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"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="Ds_Signature" value="jWWSm5xrRjxo0LoD4joa6mrBgw4rMg1t8/2nTWAjgjs="/>
            <input type="hidden" name="Ds_SignatureVersion" value="HMAC_SHA256_V1"/>
            <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" id="btn_submit" value="Send"  >
        </form>
    <script>document.forms["redsys_form"].submit();</script>
```

pero no se como podría ejecutar ese código en un iframe.

El código del controller es este:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $importe = $request->get('importe');
        $nomape = $request->get('nomape');

        $desc = 'Pago completo';
        $importe = str_replace(',', '.', $importe);


        $pago = PagoTarjeta::create([
            'iden'   => bin2hex(random_bytes(8)),
            'nomape' => $nomape,
            'importe'=> $importe,
            'desc'   => $desc,
            'id_empleado' => auth()->user()->id,
            'id_estado' => 1,
            'id_precontrato' => $request->has('_id_precontrato') ? $request->_id_precontrato : null
        ]);

        /*if(!$pago) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.pago_tarjeta.index')->withErrors('pago_tarjeta', 'No se ha podido crear la transacción correctamente..');
        }*/

        $pago->update(['norder' => config('redsys.serie.PT').str_pad($pago->id, 10, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT)]);

        try {
            $key = config('redsys.key');

            Redsys::setAmount($importe);
            Redsys::setOrder($pago->norder);
            Redsys::setMerchantcode(config('redsys.merchantcode')); //Reemplazar por el código que proporciona el banco
            Redsys::setCurrency(config('redsys.currency'));
            Redsys::setTransactiontype('0');
            Redsys::setTerminal('1');
            Redsys::setMethod('T'); //Solo pago con tarjeta, no mostramos iupay
            $esto = Redsys::setNotification(route('redirecciones.notification', [
                'iden' => $pago->iden,
                'date' => base64_encode($pago->created_at)
            ])); //Url de notificacion
            Redsys::setUrlOk(route('admin.redredsys.urlok', [
                'iden' => $pago->iden,
                'date' => base64_encode($pago->created_at)
            ])); //Url OK
            Redsys::setUrlKo(route('admin.redredsys.urlko', [
                'iden' => $pago->iden,
                'date' => base64_encode($pago->created_at)
            ])); //Url KO
            Redsys::setVersion(config('redsys.version'));
            Redsys::setTradeName(config('redsys.tradename'));
            Redsys::setTitular($nomape);
            Redsys::setProductDescription($desc);
            Redsys::setEnviroment('live'); //Entorno test

            $signature = Redsys::generateMerchantSignature($key);
            $merchantSignature = Redsys::setMerchantSignature($signature);

            $form = Redsys::executeRedirection();
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $form;
    }
```

Ese código del controller, está devolviendo el form anterior junto con el script que envía dicho formulario. Me gustaría saber como podría hacer que ese form, se enviara dentro de un iframe en un modal.

Mi código de jquery es el siguiente:

```
$(".buttonPayCard").on('click', function(){
        let nomape = $("#nomape").val();
        let importe = $("#importe").val();
        let n_contrato_pay = $("#n_contrato_pay").val();
        let token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');

        $.ajax({
            'url': "{{ route('admin.pagos_tarjeta_nuevo.store') }}",
            'method': 'POST',
            'data': { '_token': token, 'importe': importe, 'nomape': nomape, 'n_contrato_pay': n_contrato_pay},
            success: function(response){
                //$("#iframeRedsys").append(response);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                var msg = '';
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    msg = 'Time out error.';
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                } else {
                    msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                }
                console.log(msg);
            },
        });
    });
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado mi problema. Se estaba usando una librería para redsys y esta tenía un método para autogenerar el formulario y enviarlo. Pero también había otro para generar el formulario y no enviarlo. El método es este:

```
$form = Redsys::createForm();
```

con este método puedo controlar todo mi proceso

Gracias por leerme